# How to have multiple views in one component in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have a component that represents navigation bar **`full-layout.component.ts`**. The items in the navigation bar are received from a server (but for the purpose of this question, I'll hard-code).

For each of the item there is a `routerLink` associated with it, so that when a user clicks on any of the items, it is directed to a component called `department.component.ts`. In this component, there is a `DepartmentService` provided which makes `http get()` request and returns an array of strings.

Currently, when I'm in **`full-layout.component.ts`** and click on any item, it directs me there perfectly and shows correct data. But when I try to click another item from there, it doesn't do anything, and I'm not sure why.

**NB:** All of the items in the navigation bar shows list of departments from the server.

Here is my code:

**The ul consist of my items**

**`full-layout.component.html`**

```
<ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
  <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of dropDownItems">
    <a #clicked class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[item.routerLink]" (click)="send(item.name)" >
      <i class="icon-puzzle"></i>{{item.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**`full-layout.component.ts`**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './full-layout.component.html',
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class FullLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  service;

  constructor(service: SharedService) { this.service = service; }
  ngOnInit() {}

  send(str) { this.service.saveData(str); }

  dropDownItems = [{
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'Artshums'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'Dentistry'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'Law'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'IOPPN'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'LSM'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'NMS'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'Nursing'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'SSPP'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/departments',
      name: 'Health'
    }
  ];
}
```

**`departments.component.ts`**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-departments',
  templateUrl: './departments.component.html',
  providers: [DepartmentsService]
})
export class DepartmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  router; service; myName; _faculty: Faculty;

  constructor(service: SharedService, private departmentsService: DepartmentsService) {
    this.service = service;
    this.myName = service.getData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myName);
    this.departmentsService.getData(this.myName).then(
      (faculties: Faculty) => this._faculty = faculties
    );
  }
}
```

**`departments.service.ts`**

```
@Injectable()
export class DepartmentsService {
  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  getData(facultyName): Promise < any > {
    return this.http.get('/admin/faculty/' + facultyName).toPromise().then(response => response.json()).catch(DepartmentsService.handleError);
  }
}
```

**`departments.component.html`**

```
<ul class="departments-box" *ngFor="let fac of _faculty">
  <li *ngFor="let dep of fac.Departments">
    {{dep}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Question

How Can I achieve that when the user is in any of the item, it should show the right info and update view?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: there's no error. It just doesn't do anything. Ive checked console.log(), no errors @Aravind

Answer (score 0):

You can use the route parameter and ActivatedRoute in angular2

Modify in your **full-layout.html** by passing the name as a route parameter.

```
 <a #clicked class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="
           [item.routerLink,item.name]">
```

Access the parameter in your **app-departments** as

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

departmentName: string = ""; // used for the route parameter.

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,.....) {
    this.departmentName= route.snapshot.params.name;

  }

ngOnInit(){
   this.departmentsService.getData(this.myName).then(
      (faculties: Faculty) => this._faculty = faculties
    );
}
```

your routing url should be modified as

```
/components/departments/:name
```

Comment: sorry `route.snapshot.params.name;` name is not recognised. Whats that?
I modify the routing as well. And still doesn't recognise it

Comment: do u have teamviewer?

Comment: Yes, I do. How shall I send you my details?

Comment: reach me out in fb @aravind2109

Comment: Request sent. Please check